# How to connect my magento to the bank account

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I have a magento installed and ready to go, the only thing is I cant do a actuall transaction and get the money from my bank. any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get a merchant account.  There are numerous providers of these, but be very careful, the legal and financial pitfalls are as numerous as the providers.

You will probably find some interesting reading on sites like Merchant Maverick: http://www.merchantmaverick.com, their discussion of "Liquidated Damages" should be required reading for all online merchants.

Answer (score 2):

Peter's answer is required reading, but if you'd like to get started quickly Paypal is built in and offers a great integration into Magento. This should help you get started (of course you'll need to sign up for a Paypal account and link it to your bank): http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-paypal-for-your-magento-store/

Comment: I agree, services like PayPal can save you a lot of problems at the cost of a higher percentage.